# AngularJS - promise does not work with $route

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm trying to use promise with ngRoute. I've read about resolve but I'm not able to make it works. Template just gets promise object insteed of messages array. This is how it looks like:

```
angular.module('myModule', ['ngRoute'])

.factory('MessageResolver', ['$q', '$timeout', function($q, $timeout)
{                   
    var x = function()
    {                 
        var deferred = $q.defer();

        $timeout(function() 
        {
            deferred.resolve(['Hello', 'world!']);
        }, 2000);

        return deferred.promise;  
    }       

    return {
        getMessage : x
    }
}])

.controller('HelloCtrl', ['$scope', 'MessageResolver', function($scope, MessageResolver)
{                      
    $scope.messages = MessageResolver.getMessage();
}])
.config(['$routeProvider', function($routeProvider) 
{
    $routeProvider.when('/', 
    {
        templateUrl: 'index2.html', 
        controller: "HelloCtrl",
        resolve: ['MessageResolver']
    }); 
}])  

;
```

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the docs:

> factory - {string|function}: If string then it is an alias for a service. Otherwise if function, then it is injected and the return value is treated as the dependency.

Hence, your `service` must return a promise for it to be resolved. Try this:

```js
var resolver = ['$q', '$timeout', function($q, $timeout)
{                   
        var deferred = $q.defer();

        $timeout(function() 
        {
            deferred.resolve(['Hello', 'world!']);
        }, 2000);

        return deferred.promise;  
}]

// ...

.config(['$routeProvider', function($routeProvider) 
{
    $routeProvider.when('/', 
    {
        templateUrl: 'index2.html', 
        controller: "HelloCtrl",
        resolve: { 'MessageResolver': resolver }
    }); 
}])
```

And if you want to use it as a service:

```
angular.module('myModule', ['ngRoute'])

.factory('MessageResolver', ['$q', '$timeout', function($q, $timeout)
{                               
    var deferred = $q.defer();

    $timeout(function() 
    {
        deferred.resolve(['Hello', 'world!']);
    }, 2000);

    return deferred.promise;    
}])                

.controller('HelloCtrl', ['$scope', 'MessageResolver', function($scope, MessageResolver)
{                     
    MessageResolver.then(function(messages)
    {
        $scope.messages = messages;
    })                            

}])

.config(['$routeProvider', function($routeProvider) 
{
    $routeProvider.when('/', 
    {
        templateUrl: 'index2.html', 
        controller: "HelloCtrl",
        resolve: { 'MessageResolver': 'MessageResolver' }
    }); 
}])
```

Working Demo: http://plnkr.co/edit/6pAHrCY6Du68lEa3vBEx?p=preview

Comment: Thank you for your reply. It seems to work fine but I would like to avoid any globals. That's why I've decided to try use service. My code works fine when I'm not using $routeProvider (controller defined by ng-controller). I do not need to wait until all promises will be resolved to show my page. All I want to achive is to use promise with routnig :)

Comment: I works perfectly fine when I use .then() in the controller (https://gist.github.com/ayeo/7936126). I looks extremly ugly way. Why it works whithout (then) when I'm not using ngRoute?

Comment: I've just found that automatic promises unwraping has been rejected since 1.2.x. So question is, why it works whithout ngRoute? :)

Comment: @ayeo The promises do not unwrap in templates. However, the example you posted in the Gist works with some changes while using `resolve` syntax. I have updated the answer.